# Legendre's proof involving linearity independence

Tags: legendre-symbol

Show that any polynomial of degree n is a linear combination of P0(x), P1(x), ..., Pn(x)

Actually I have no idea how to start with a proof involving "any". Can someone help??

Comment: See one of my other posts on this subject: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/512295/using-legendre-polynomial-to-approximate-any-polynomial/770500#770500

Answer (score 0):

gram schmidt orthogonalization process under inner product$$ \int _{-1}^{1} f(x)g(x)dx$$ may help.

Comment: another approach may be from legendre equation

Comment: can you elaborate more?

Comment: basically on applying gram schmidt orthogonalization process under given inner product on P(x) would give some scalar multiple of P0(x), P1(x), ..., Pn(x) implying that they are orthogonal hence linearly independent